# HAPPY NEW YEAR rebus!

Tags: visual, rebus

HAPPY NEW YEAR 2018! Best wishes to everyone for this new year. I have found a new HAPPY NEW YEAR REBUS! Try to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> (This year) **Happiness is Good, Sadness is Bad**. (Happy New Year?)

Explanation:

> Using Boolean algebra, 
>  $$a=good$$ 
>
>  $$x=a'=bad $$
> $$ y=a.a'=0 $$
> $$ z=(a')'=a=good $$ 
>  Happy smiley gets, 
> $$ yz+zz = 0 + good = good$$ 
>  Sad smiley gets,
>  
> $$xx+xy= bad+ 0= bad$$
>  
>  **HAPPY NEW YEAR!**